# The character in my anylogic are wrong, they change with the two following character, what can i do?

Tags: anylogic

I have a real problem with Anylogic. Whe i create a model in the section palette and also the names of objects is writed with the next character. I mean if a call an object 'abc' it will be call 'cde' and i cant read nothing. Can someone help me with this? Thank you all.

Comment: never heard of this, screenshot and some info on your OS would be helpful ;-)

Comment: Truly bizarre. Is this for a specific model or all models? A long time, and many AnyLogic versions ago, I encountered a strange naming bug, but not of the type you describe, and it was fixed by recreating the relevant Agent Type (which was thankfully relatively simple). The symptoms you describe sound as though they have a deeper root. Have you tried reinstalling Java?